# Fetch emails from email servers in php

Tags: php, email

I write code to fetch emails from different servers (Gmail,yahoo,hotmail etc).I tested my code on gmail server and it worked, but for yahoo that code doesn't work.My code is :

```
$data array will be like 

$data['type'] = 'pop3 or imap';
$data['protocol_type'] = 'ssl or tls or none';
$data['port'] = '993 or 995';
$data['login_name'] = 'user name';
$data['password'] = 'user password';
public function testconnectionAction()
    {

        $data = $_POST;


        if($data['type'] == 'pop3' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'none')
        {
               $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'/pop3}INBOX';
             $username = $data['login_name'];
              $password = $data['password'];
            $imap = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)or die(imap_last_error());

            if (!imap_ping($imap)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
        }elseif($data['type'] == 'imap' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'none') {
             $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'}INBOX';
             $username = $data['login_name'];
              $password = $data['password'];
            $imap = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
            if (!imap_ping($imap)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
        }
      if($data['type'] == 'pop3' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'ssl')
      {
             $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'/pop3/ss}INBOX';
             $username = $data['login_name'];
             $password = $data['password'];
            $imap = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
      //  
            if (!imap_ping($imap)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
      }
      if($data['type'] == 'imap' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'ssl')
      {
        $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
        $username = $data['login_name'];
        $password = $data['password'];

/* try to connect */
        $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

            if (!imap_ping($inbox)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
      }

       if($data['type'] == 'pop3' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'tls')
      {
             $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'/pop3/tls}INBOX';
             $username = $data['login_name'];
             $password = $data['password'];
             $imap = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)or die(imap_last_error());
            if (!imap_ping($imap)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
      }
      if($data['type'] == 'imap' && $data['protocol_type'] == 'tls')
      {
        $hostname = '{'.$data['host'].':'.$data['port'].'/imap/tls}INBOX';
             $username = $data['login_name'];
             $password = $data['password'];
             $imap = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

            if (!imap_ping($imap)) {
                echo "Test Failed.";
                }else{
                      echo "Test Successfull.";
                }
      }

    }
```

How can i test that code work on yahoo or not.i try to enter pop.yahoo.com for host and port 995 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search and testing i found the yahoo email settings for testing .

```
Incoming Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com Port 993 with SSL
Outgoing Server: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com Port 465 with SSL (requires Authentication to be enabled)
Username: Your Business Email address (e.g. name@mycompany.com)
Password: Your Business Email password
```

While for Hotmail i use below code :

```
Outlook.com Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop3.live.com (logon using Secure Password Authentication – SPA,SSL enabled mail server port: 995).Hope it help someone like me.
```